# AS3: Enable features according to Flash Player Version

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, version, flash, detection

I'd like to know if it is possible to enable/disable some piece of code according to Flash Player version in ActionScript 3.

Let's say; I have a custom class `customClass` that uses `flash.media.Microphone`. The Microphone class has a property `isSupported` which is available for Flash Player version 10.1 and above (as stated in the documentation). I implement this property in my customClass... so:

I need something like this (by checking with the built-in `Capabilities.version`):

```
if (version >= 10.1) {
    trace(_mic.isSupported); //this will throw an error if the debug version is not 10.1 or later
} else { 
    doSmthElse();
}
```

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only way I know:

```
if (version >= 10.1) {
    trace(_mic["isSupported"]); //this will throw an error if the debug version is not 10.1 or later
} else { 
    doSmthElse();
}
```

With the bracket access syntaxt the verifier won't try to check whether the method or property is defined in advance (at load time, I think). So your code will only be evaluated at runtime, if it actually runs.

Comment: thanks.. this helps at least.. I also figured to double-check with hasOwnProperty(..)..

Comment: I presume you could do you version check in javascript and use the ExternalInterface API to recieve a msg from the js in Flex, and have a switch case function to enable/disable features.

Comment: @Brian Bishop. I guess you could, but that's just more work for no real benefit, I think. The problem is not detecting the current version, which is trivial in Actionscript. The problem is that the verifier validates whether the property is defined or not (which depends on the player version) when it loads the swf. So if you wrote `_mic.isSupported` this will produce an error in version < 10, *whether you actually run that piece of code or not*.

Comment: By the way, Microphone.isSupported is a static property. So hasOwnProperty check won't work with it but bracket access syntax works.